# Running Polymer demos in NodeJS on windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, polymer

I finally got NodeJS, Git and Polymer all configured on my windows 7 machine, how do I get NodeJS to run it? When I try node polymer it throws an error saying module.js is missing. I am a complete newbie with Node...

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Polymer is a client side library. It builds a set of abstractions on top of the HTML DOM and is intended to be run inside of a browser, not on the server side.

To use Polymer with a node.js server use something like [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static) to serve the polymer assets down to the browser.